# Javascript - How do I have a get/set in a method? (e.g. pineapple.is_a.fruit)

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, multi-level

I have an assignment where I'm supposed to make magic out of programming.
I'm unable to find any answers online, as I do not know the search term for it (tried method in a method etc...). Appreciate any help given!

Here's what I got:
I need to create a class that builds upon itself.
e.g.

```
const pineapple = new Item('pineapple');
pineapple.type = fruit // this is simple

pineapple.is_a.fruit = true // this I do not know
pineapple.is.heavy = true // same thing
```

I do not even know where to begin.
My attempt is similar to this, but I'm getting undefined.

```
class Thing {
  constructor(type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
  
  is_a(bool) {
    this.fruit = this.is_a(bool);
  }
}
```

Comment: `get is_a() { return this; }`? You can do the same with `is` and just return the same object for it. But I don't know what the expected outcome is and whether this approach covers it.

Comment: Look up "javascript getters and setters"

Comment: I to not really understand what you want to do. Is it possible that you post (at least a relevant part of) your assignment?

Comment: This might also involved proxy objects.

Comment: It's not clear what you need to do. Are the `is_a` and `is` defined in advance? Are the `is_a.fruit` and `is.heavy` properties defined in advance? Or is it dynamic somehow? If dynamic, this will require a Proxy (if not more than one), but it seems unlikely that you've been asked to do something so odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that they can be defined in advance, in order to have sub-properties like `pineapple.is_a.fruit`, you'll need to define objects on the object's `is_a` and `is` properties. For instance (see comments):

```js
class Item { // `Item` rather than `Thing`, right?
    constructor(type) {
        this.type = type;
        // Create an `is_a` property that's an object with a `fruit` property
        this.is_a = {
            fruit: false // Or whatever the initial value should be
        };
        // Create an `is` property that's an object with a `heavy` property
        this.is = {
            heavy: false // Or whatever the initial value should be
        };
    }
}

const pineapple = new Item('pineapple');
pineapple.type = "fruit"; // I added quotes here

console.log("is_a.fruit before:", pineapple.is_a.fruit);
console.log("is.heavy before:", pineapple.is_a.fruit);

pineapple.is_a.fruit = true;
pineapple.is.heavy = true;

console.log("is_a.fruit after: ", pineapple.is_a.fruit);
console.log("is.heavy after: ", pineapple.is_a.fruit);
```

Comment: Thank you! This was what I'm looking for.